# How to make a screenshot in MonoGame for Windows?

Tags: c#, monogame

So I've been trying to create image files from the current game window (a screenshot essentially) but what I've tried so far just isn't working. The methods `RenderTarget2D.SaveAsPng()` and `RenderTarget2D.SaveAsJpeg()` aren't implemented yet by the MonoGame developers to use for Windows...

So I'm wondering, is there an alternative?

Here's a sample code that, when run, throws the NotImplemented error, for anyone curious:

```
Stream stream = new FileStream("screenshot.jpg", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
screenshot.SaveAsJpeg(stream, 320, 180);
stream.Close();
```

The variable `screenshot` is a `RenderTarget2D` object where the game screen was drawn in.

Thanks for reading, I hope to get some help.

Comment: Can you share how you drew the game screen into a `RenderTarget2D` object? I'd like to use this method to save my game screen, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that step. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SaveAsJpeg is defined as:

```
public void SaveAsJpeg(Stream stream, int width, int height)
{
#if WINDOWS_STOREAPP
    SaveAsImage(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, stream, width, height);
#elif WINDOWS_PHONE

    var pixelData = new byte[Width * Height * GraphicsExtensions.Size(Format)];
    GetData(pixelData);

    var waitEvent = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(width, height);
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(pixelData, 0, bitmap.Pixels, 0, pixelData.Length);
        bitmap.SaveJpeg(stream, width, height, 0, 100);
        waitEvent.Set();
    });

    waitEvent.Wait();
#elif MONOMAC
    SaveAsImage(stream, width, height, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
#else
    throw new NotImplementedException();
#endif
}
```

Can you add

```
#define WINDOWS_STOREAPP
```

in your main class.

Comment: I tried this, it does recognize the constant being set but it still throws an NotImplemented error. I tried with all the possible constants, but none seem to work.